# Exceeding AWS RDS memory threshold with .NET Core app

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I've tried upgrading the RDS instance, which worked for a while, but I'm still running into an issue where my freeable memory threshold is reached and the database then suffers from performance issues.

Obviously I can reboot the instance, which is a temporary fix.

I'm a bit in the dark as to how I can diagnose WHERE the memory is being used. It seems like no matter the instance, I hit the threshold. I've got a database with roughly 200,000 items that have multiple child tables (10+).

Any diagnostic tools or logs I should be aware of?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server Express 12.00.4422.0.v1

Comment: Did you perform remote debugging of your ASP.NET Core application to see its memory usage and grab a snapshot?

Comment: Wouldn't that be the memory usage of the EC2 instance and not the database?